# Add subtitles through video controls to go directory into caption video with HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to add subtitles through the video controls to go directly into the caption video with JavaScript in HTML?
This code adds video from the control, but I need add subtitles.

```js
const videoPlayer = document.getElementById('mty');

function loadFile(event) {
     videoPlayer.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
}
```